# ZeroMQ dealer socket receive call throws null exception trying to receive second message

Tags: c#, zeromq

I am implementing the router->dealer pattern. On the Dealer (client side) I get the first message fine. When trying to receive the second message I get a null reference.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ZeroMQ.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
public void Connect(string user)
    {
        context = new ZContext();
        socket = new ZSocket(context, ZSocketType.DEALER);

        socket.IdentityString = user;    // Set a printable identity
        socket.Connect("tcp://192.168.1.154:5671");

        ZMessage msg = null;
        ZError error;

        MessageHandler.MsgOut += new MessageHandler.onSendMsg(SendMessage);

            while (true)
            {

                if (socket.ReceiveMessage(ref msg, ZSocketFlags.DontWait, out error))
                {                          
                    if (error == ZError.ETERM)
                {
                    return;    // Interrupted
                    throw new ZException(error);
                }

                using (msg)
                {
                    MessageHandler.ReceiveMessage(msg);
                }

                }

              }
      }

    public void SendMessage(byte[] msg)
    {
        socket.Send(msg, 0, msg.Length);
    }
```

Comment: I fixed it by moving the ZMessage msg = null; to after the While(true) statement